# ¿Cómo puedo conseguir que mi página ASP.NET Web Api devuelva JSON en vez de XML usando chrome?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

Usando el nuevo **ASP.NET Web API** en **Chrome** estoy viendo **XML**.

- ¿Cómo puedo cambiarlo para que me devuelva **JSON** para que pueda verlo en mi navegador?.
- Creo que es solo parte de la cabecera de la petición, ¿estoy en los cierto?

> Pregunta original: [How do I get ASP.NET Web API to return JSON instead of XML using Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, esto es como que tuvieras una estantería de vasos de agua, y quisieras berber agua, tus opciones son múltiples.

Yo pienso que lo mejor es que te sujetes a un estandar como respuesta, esto, siguiendo el principio de robustez (ley de Postel):

> ser conservador en lo que haces/envías, ser liberal en lo que aceptas de otros.

[Fuente 1(Inglés)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) y [Fuente 2 (español)](http://www.lnds.net/blog/2008/09/el-principio-de-robustez.html)

Partiendo de esto, creo que es recomendable que desde tu API te decidas a enviar un formato y que tu cliente (lo que sea que consuma el API, lo pueda manejar). Si quieres enviar multiples formatos, está bien, pero le informas a tu cliente el cuál a través de los headers te dirá qué versión de la respuesta acepta, tal como dijo [JosEduSol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/1793/917).

Las otras maneras que puedes lograrlo son las siguientes:

**Agregando la respuesta JSON por defecto.**
*Agrega lo siguiente al `WebApiConfig.cs`*

```cs
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

**Removiendo la respuesta XML.**
*Esta es mi forma preferida de hacerlo*

```cs
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
```

Luego puedes jugar con el JSON que retornas, como decidir si será CamelCase, o si estará identado, por ejemplo:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Nota: la ley de Postel es más aplicable al contenido que retornas y no a su formato, es decir, si retornas un `animal`, siempre retorna un `animal`, no un arreglo de animales, y mucho menos una `persona`, aunque yo entiendo que es bueno ser explícito con los formatos que tu aplicación retorna, así tu cliente sabrá qué esperar exactamente.

Answer (score 3):

Depende del navegador, por ejemplo desde Internet Explorer el formato por defecto es JSON, pero como has notado desde Chrome el formato por defecto es XML.

Una posible solución es utilizar alguna herramienta como [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) (extensión de Chrome) o [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) y configurar la cabecera:

```
Accept: application/json
```

para recibir la respuesta como JSON.

Por ejemplo, en Postman:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET WEB API, por defecto retorna XML

Para que la respuesta sea en formato JSON se edita el fichero **App_Start \ WebApiConfig.cs**
En este fichero, en **Register** agregar como primera línea de código lo siguiente:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]